# Expression Criteria for Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've created a database with about 15000 records and I want to create a form that filters the records according to entries inputed in textboxes through a Query. For the most of my columns i've used this Expression :

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Testform]![Testtxt] & "*"
```

I use "Like" so that if the user decides not to input anything in a textbox, the query ignores that parameter. However when it comes to Dates (I have two columns that contain Dates) I can't make it ignore the empty textbox when the user decides not to write anything. Can you help me make the expression below show all the records in the query if the DateTesttxt is empty ?

```
> [Forms]![TestForm]![DateTesttxt]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using query designer, just add another condition

```
Is Null
```

so visually in query builder it will be something like:

```
Criteria: > [Forms]![TestForm]![DateTesttxt]
      or: Is Null
```

UPDATE:

This should work as well as a single expression:

```
Is Null Or > [Forms]![TestForm]![DateTesttxt]
```

and it is more correct solution in case if you have conditions on more than one column